# AICC Runtime API

Tags: scorm

I am new to AICC eLearning courses, I was perviously working on SCORM 1.2 in which I was using SCORM 1.2 Runtime API calls to keep track of users activity in the course. But i could not find any proper documentation for AICC to handle them. Does anyone have any boilerplate HTML/Javascript template which i can use in order to launch the course and keep track of users activity.

I have the following files

.au

.crs

.cst

.des

I need to know how to embed all these files under a iFrame and using Javascript handle the user events similar to SCORM 1.2.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

The API for AICC is quite different from SCORM. The various [specifications are available here](https://github.com/ADL-AICC/AICC-Document-Archive) of which the one you'll spend the most time with is [CMI001 - AICC/CMI Guidelines For Interoperability](https://github.com/ADL-AICC/AICC-Document-Archive/releases/tag/cmi001v4).

It mentions three bindings:

- File-based (non-browser, local LAN type communications via files)
- Communicating via HTTP (The HACP Binding)
- Communicating via API (probably the closest to SCORM)

In practice, I have only ever seen HACP binding used in the wild.

It entails the content being launched with the AICC session ID and communications URL being passed as GET parameters to the URL. Armed with that you perform GetParam and PutParam POST calls among others, passing what looks similar to an INI config file as the payload. Finish with an ExitAU call.

If your content resides on a different server to the management system, then cross-domain communication issues can come into play. The most common solution is a relay residing on the content's server to act as a proxy to the management system server.